# Javascript replace text within <title> with <span>title</span>

Tags: javascript, html, replace

Hi i want to replace my javascript string solution like this.

```
input:- this is <title> and <heading> 
output:- this is <span>title</span> and <span>heading</span>
```

can anyone help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you want to achieve it via js?

Comment: you have to parse string you need to search for title use `includes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
var input = "this is <title> and <heading>";
var output = input.replace(/<([^>]+)>/g, "<span>$1</span>");
console.log(output);
```

That is, match an opening `<`, followed by one or more non-`>` characters captured as a submatch so that you can reference it as `$1` in the replacement string, followed by a closing `>`.

Answer (score 2):

use regex to replace

```
input.replace(/</g, '<span_').replace(/>/g,'</span>').replace(/_/g,'>');
```

Comment: i try that it is not working because when apply replace second time out <span> already have '>' so it replace this also. like 
`this is <span</span>title</span> and <span</span>heading</span>`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
input.replace(/<[a-zA-Z]*>/g, '<span>$&</span>');
```

Explanation:
`.replace` encloses all tags in ''. `'$&` is replaced with the tag. See this for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Example:

```js
var ta = document.getElementById('ta'), output = document.getElementById('output');
ta.value = 'I have <title> and <head> (this is just example text, you can replace).';
function replaceIt() {
  output.innerText = ta.value.replace(/<[a-zA-Z]*>/g, '<span>$&</span>');
  // Okay, technically Node#innerText is non-standard, so use an HTML escape function on production sites.
  // For demo purposes, I just chose innerText for ease of use
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
<button onclick="replaceIt()">Enclose tags in &ltspan&gt s.</button>
<div>Output:</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative

```
var output = input.split("<").join("#").split(">").join("</span>").split("#").join("<span>");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Isn't `.join("@").split("@")` redundant?